# Liferay: Create-account hook functionality

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6

I have recently taken interest in Liferay portals.
Today I created a create account hook that is a drop down of some values I've set.

My problem is, that the hook has no functionality.  Essentially, I want to have the users organization set from the dropdown.  (Select org 1, you get put in org 1).  Is there a way to be able to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Liferay. Unfortunately I have no clue what you're trying to do. A hook changes Liferay's behaviour while you're talking about some functionality that is typically attached to a portlet. You can change Liferay's UI with a hook, but then we'd need to know what part you're trying to change. And even then, portlets will be a better start than hooks. You'll find introductory material on https://dev.liferay.com, illustrating your first steps.

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch all organizations by using below code and then add user into selected organizations.

OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations(WorkflowConstants.ALL_POS, WorkflowConstants.ALL_POS);